# Jasny Bootstrap offcanvas menu padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I used offcanvas menu from Jasny Bootstrap for my latest project.

Now my issue is how can I set a padding-right to mobile nav elements? The problem is that the menu names are too long for portrait mode of phones, therefore I need to have a line-break.

Adding it here does not help, but why?

```
 .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please add a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Finally I have tried to create my first jsfiddle. 
Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/tinusmile/dnq8jhbu/

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Sorry, here's the working one: http://jsfiddle.net/tinusmile/dnq8jhbu/31/